# Java Stream API - count items of a nested list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's assume that we have a list of countries: `List<Country>` and each country has a reference to a list of its regions: `List<Region>`  (e.g. states in the case of the USA). Something like this:

```
USA
  Alabama
  Alaska
  Arizona
  ...

Germany
  Baden-Württemberg
  Bavaria
  Brandenburg
  ...
```

In "plain-old" Java we can count all regions e.g. this way:

```
List<Country> countries = ...
int regionsCount = 0;

for (Country country : countries) {
    if (country.getRegions() != null) {
        regionsCount += country.getRegions().size();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same goal with Java 8 Stream API? I thought about something similar to this, but I don't know how to count items of nested lists using `count()` method of stream API:

```
countries.stream().filter(country -> country.getRegions() != null).???
```

Comment: IMHO this @fabian solution should be preferred. `List::size` is an `O(1)` operation whilst using a `flatMap` on every list is an `O(n)` operation.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could use `map()` to get a `Stream` of region lists and then [`mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) to get the number of regions for each country. After that use [`sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) to get the sum of all the values in the `IntStream`:

```
countries.stream().map(Country::getRegions) // now it's a stream of regions
                  .filter(rs -> rs != null) // remove regions lists that are null
                  .mapToInt(List::size) // stream of list sizes
                  .sum();
```

**Note:** The benefit of using `getRegions` before filtering is that you don't need to call `getRegions` more than once.

Comment: Side note, you can use `Objects::nonNull` instead of `rs -> rs != null`

Comment: Is there a way to get country name and its number of regions? instead of total number of regions across all countries?

Comment: Is there a way to return a list containing sizes of individual regions instead?

Comment: @ashwanikumar If you do not use `sum` in the end, and use `map` instead of `mapToInt`, you get an `Stream<Integer>` which could be converted to a list using the appropriate collector.

Answer (score 10):

You may map each country to number of regions and then reduce result using sum:

```
countries.stream()
  .map(c -> c.getRegions() == null ? 0 : c.getRegions().size())
  .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: .reduce(Integer::sum) :)

Answer (score 1):

You could even use `flatMap()` like:

```
countries.stream().map(Country::getRegions).flatMap(List::stream).count();

where,

map(Country::getRegions) = returns a Stream<List<Regions>>
flatMap(List::stream) = returns a Stream<Regions>
```

Comment: Disclaimer: This approach may be slower if Java enumerates the Region objects in the stream. In this case, it will be better to go with @fabian's solution.