# I want to count the number of Collections in a Collection, in a Collection with Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a `SchoolDistrict`, that has many `Schools`, that has many `Students` that have many `Classes`.

I want to count the number of classes given a SchoolDistrict.

The Java 7 way would be like so:

```
Integer classCount = 0;
for (School school : schoolDistrict)
{
    for (Student student : school.getStudents())
    {
        classCount += student.getClasses().size();
    }
}
```

I know that Java 8 brings streams that are supposed to make this kind of thing a bit easier on the eyes.

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Any takers?

EDIT: someone marked this as a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317862/java-stream-api-count-items-of-a-nested-list), I don't believe it is as that example only went 2 levels deep (Countries to Regions). My question relates to a problem that goes four levels deep (SchoolDistricts to Schools to Students to Classes)

Comment: @azurefrog almost, but I need to go one level deeper with my Collections query

Comment: Maybe try something like this:     `schoolDistrict.stream().mapToInt( school -> school.getStudents().getClasses().size() ).sum();`

Comment: @Orin2005 you can't do `getStudents().getClasses()` as `getStudents()` returns a Collection, which doesn't contain `Class`es in this case.

Comment: Whoops... sorry it should look something like this then `schoolDistrict.stream().flatMap(school -> school.getStudents().stream()).flatMap(students -> students.getClasses().stream()).mapToInt(classes -> classes.getSize()).sum();`

Comment: Why are you using an `Integer` instead of `int`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses method references to get the job done sans lambdas:

```
int classCount = schoolDistrict.stream()
  .map(School::getStudents)
  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
  .map(Student::getClasses)
  .mapToInt(Collection::size)
  .sum();
```

Note also the switch to an `IntStream` of the *sizes* of each student's classes then applying `sum()`, which is of course more efficient than streaming each class for each student and counting up the classes iteratively.

Comment: This looks a little prettier.

Comment: I don't think the `.flatMap(List::stream).map` part will work

Comment: @Kayaman it takes more steps to use only method references (no lambdas), but I agree it looks cleaner and you can follow it more easily IMHO

Comment: I get the following error with @Bohemian's code: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to <unknown>

Comment: @Trevor it compiles and runs OK for me (Note I had a typo in the code - a missing colon between `List` and `stream`, now corrected)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious with `List`... is `List` a static import of something? I'm assuming it's not the java.util.List type, as that one doesn't define a stream method (and that's why my code wasn't compiling)

Comment: @Trevor it is the [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which is a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), which has a [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) method. Perhaps you have either not imported `java.util.List`, or you have defined your own `List` class in your package, or you have another library that defines a `List` class earlier in your classpath than the JDK

Comment: Ah, I figured out the issue... in my actual code, I don't have a List of Students, I have a SortedSet of Students, so I needed to say `.flatMap(SortedSet::stream)`... silly me

Comment: @Trevor Even more general, use `Collection::stream` and `Collection::size`, which will always work no matter which actual collection you use. I should have done that in the first place! (answer updated)

Comment: With lambda expressions, i.e. `s -> s.getStudents().stream()`, you didn’t have the problem. By the way, in Java 9, it won’t matter whether you use `.flatMap(s -> s.getClasses().stream()).count()` or `.mapToInt(s -> s.getClasses().size()).sum()`  (unless, there are more than 2³¹ elements, of course)…

Answer (score 4):

You can use `schoolDistrict.stream().flatMap(school -> school.getStudents().stream())` to get a `Stream<Student>`. You can further do a second `flatMap()` to get a `Stream<YourClass>`. This is when you need to process each entity of nested collections. If you only need to count the amounts, you can use `mapToInt()` and `sum()` as the end operation.

So `flatMap()` is the secret to unnesting or "flattening" nested collections.

```
Stream<MyClass> stream = schoolDistrict.stream().flatMap(s -> s.getStudents().stream()).flatMap(s -> s.getClasses().stream());
int count = stream.count();
```

Comment: I knew flatMap had something to do with it... but it was adding in the extra `.stream()` inside the flapMap lambda function that I was missing. Many thanks